# Creating geth nodes in virtual machines

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, ether, node-discovery

I have 2 nodes
the first node is on my machine ( host ) with an address 192.168.1.4
the second node is on Virtual machine with an address 192.168.1.8
the ping working fine, but when I used this commands:

bootnode:

> bootnode -nodekey boot.key -addr 192.168.1.4:30305

**node1 :**

> geth --datadir node1 --http --http.api "eth,net,web3,personal,admin,miner" --http.corsdomain "*" --ipcpath node1/geth.ipc --port 30305 --bootnodes enode://5bfe04ebbcab7fa3fc5d0af526454c4b690664f1a69ef53192c50183d49ea101d0eabf4085ef537cf9dfa7e7d069a26b8fe5d10c3b43cfc55ba0a832870aa9f1@192.168.1.4:0?discport=30305  --networkid 12345 --unlock 0x7cAD04e643e79a937e5Fb509f5783666f1336Fb1 --password node1/password.txt --authrpc.port 8554 --mine --miner.etherbase="0x7cAD04e643e79a937e5Fb509f5783666f1336Fb1" --allow-insecure-unlock --http.port 8545

**node2 :**

> geth --datadir node2 --http --http.api "eth,net,web3,personal,admin,miner" --http.corsdomain "*" --ipcpath node2/geth.ipc --port 30307 --bootnodes enode://1d17187c4103083dcce0e86cba46799fb7aea5a6f99aca529f4548c4c6cfb33c829c517fbc7bcf52d4d6bcff628b15b4c16d24554de7d4d083fa07b59fb40a2f@192.168.1.4:0?discport=30306  --networkid 12345 --unlock 0xbd1d64Ca9F6b3775803ea22406e80E8313C0fa69 --password node2/password.txt --authrpc.port 8555 --mine --miner.etherbase="0xbd1d64Ca9F6b3775803ea22406e80E8313C0fa69" --http.port 8546 --allow-insecure-unlock

There is no connection between the 2 nodes
it shows me this on the node2

[image]